# Geting rid of the Index number while passing an Array to cell names through Report Generation VI Labview

Tags: excel, labview

I have a VI that gets Data and stores them into different Arrays. Then I try to pass this Data to Excel using the Report Generation VI Labview. I am using a custom Format Template and I created my Own cell names. However, these cell names only should  contain the Value and I want to get rid of the Index. How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: Please post a picture of your current code. Select your code and chose Edit >> Create VI Snippet From Selection. This will give you a PNG that you can post that we can just drag onto our block diagrams to recreate your code.

Comment: Hello, I found no where around it so I decided to create a table and input it into excel instead. It works this way for my needs. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a solution to the problem but a way around it. Instead of trying to filter out the index numbers, I created a table and just imported the table in excel!